# back icon is missing in Appbar.BackAction in react native paper lib

Tags: react-native, react-native-paper

I'm using Appbar component of **react-native-paper** in React Native app. back click is working fine but app icon is not coming check screenshot. Please help me .

```
<Appbar.Header style={{ backgroundColor: '#fff' }}>
         <Appbar.BackAction onPress={this._goBack} />
         <Appbar.Content
                 title="Login" />
</Appbar.Header>
```

[image]

Please help how can convert it in back button. I'm following this artilce https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/appbar-header.html

Comment: Can you give some more details? Because your code is ok and they run perfectly in my machine.

Answer (score 4):

You need to add

```
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"
```

in `android/app/build.gradle`

(cf [react-native-vector-icons](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons#option-with-gradle-recommended) )

Answer (score 1):

react native paper uses react-native-vector-icons npm package, you need  to manually link this package to your react native paper project using "react-native link react-native-vector-icons". do this and re build your project using "react-native run-android".
[react-native-vector-icons](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/icons.html)